# Editing Orchard CMS themes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, orchardcms

I have installed a new theme for my Orchard CMS site, but the new theme doesn't want to appear in the "Solution Explorer" window in Visual Studio 2010. The theme works fine on the site and the folder appears when looking in "Windows Explorer". Does anyone know why this might be?

The default theme, "TheThemeMachine" shows up fine why not installed themes from the gallery.

Answer (score 10):

Try including the new theme into your solution.

Select the Themes project (where TheThemeMachine is), click on the Show All Files at the top of the Solution Explorer, right-click your new theme folder under the Themes project and select Include In Project. Click on Show All Files again to deselect the option.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I needed to know. :) Works perfectly in Visual Studio 2012 Professional.